# make dropdown readonly

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Though the question started with MVC4, the answer I found led to be more generic and applicable for JQuery and can be used in general

How to make a dropdown readonly (restrict from changing value) yet data available back on controller on submit?

When I am showing the for in Edit mode, I want to disable particular dropdown based on some condition. However on submit, I need the data available in the controller, so that I can use the object directly to update using EF.

If I use disabled property, the data will not be available to controller and I need to write lot of other code to get the property or skip the attribute while update.

Is there a quick workaround that can be easily applied on all screens?

Nope I don't want to disable it and enable on submit!!!

Comment: I'm not very familliar with your app, but I'm assuming the read only dropdown means you already have it in your code or db somewhere, right? So why do you have to rely on it being submitted by the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to be little generic (not just for MVC.NET)

```
$.fn.extend({
    readonlyddl: function () {
        if (this.is('[readonly]')) {
            //  save current value
            var val = this.val();
            //  remove any events that fire on change
            this.unbind("change");
            //reset the value when the select change
            this.change(function () {
                $(this).val(val);
            });
        }
    }
});

//  $("#ID").readonlyddl();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that it is the best solution, sounds like workaround, but you can add hidden input into your form with value equal to selected item from drop down (which is disabled). Drop down will be disabled and when submit the form you can get value of hidden input inside your controller.

Comment: This is tricky... I need to add lot of code in each page. Also at times it needs to be enabled, so may not be for my situation. Anyhow thanks for your thought.

Answer (score 1):

Just Showing with code what **@ntl** also answered a workaround for disabled dropdown in MVC :

Model :

```
Public int FooId {get;set;}
```

Controller:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FooId, Model.Foos, new { disabled = "disabled" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FooId)
```

If you have to disabled the dropdown dynamically with javascript then simply assign the currently selected value of the dropdown to the hidden field just after disabling it.

Now hidden field `'FooId'` will give you selected dropdown value on post controller action.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against relying on the data not being changed. The data isn't reliable anymore after it's been send to the browser and back to the server. It could easily be changed along the way.

Especially when you're updating your database 'directly'.

Comment: Agreed, but in my case, there would be client side operations and at times i need to disable changing (same as readonly textbox)